# Wordwrap word separator in PHP

Tags: php

I wish to understand the internal mechanism of wordwrap function:

```
string wordwrap ( string $str [, int $width = 75 [, string $break = "\n" [, bool $cut = false ]]] )
```

If you are using $cut = false wordwrap will only split where it finds a word separator. I assume this is the space character based on this example:

```
$str = wordwrap("--------------  ------", '5', 'b', false);
echo $str;
//Result: --------------b ------
```

My question is how does this function decides where to break? It will only search for the nearest space character closest to the width position? Are there other characters that will allow the break ?

Comment: I don't understand the close votes. Internally wordwrap is using a word splitting method for sure.

Comment: Generally the word separator would be `\n`.

Comment: no, that's the break separator, the INTERNAL word separator is a space (and maybe other characters)

Comment: Ah got it. INternal Word Separator. Well, sorry, no idea for now.

Answer (score 1):

This is not documented, but it uses the space character, i.e. `' '`, to determine the word boundaries. The first space character it finds after `$width` is replaced by the `$break` character.

See also: [`ext/standard/string.c`](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob;f=ext/standard/string.c;h=e245ce3fb6ddafb54b2730fa3d7fa144e931725e;hb=HEAD#l913)

#### Update 2015-04-22

This has been [addressed](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/phpdoc/en/trunk/reference/strings/functions/wordwrap.xml?r1=336614&r2=336613&pathrev=336614) in the documentation, based on [this bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64092).

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you see the beautiful documentation at [PHP Website](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)?

Wraps a string to a given number of characters using a string break character.

```
<?php
$text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 20, "<br />\n");

echo $newtext;
?>
```

This outputs:

```
The quick brown fox<br />
jumped over the lazy<br />
dog.
```

Comment: I updated my question. I'm talking about some special cases not covered by the manual.

Comment: @danip Well, I kinda don't understand your question. :( You wanna replace all the double spaces with `b`?

Comment: I wish to understand how wordwrap functions if I have long words. By default it will not separate the input at the exact position. It will search for a near space character and it will break there. I want to know if there are any other characters besides space that will make also have the same effect.

Comment: Yes, it takes up the next space character.

Comment: where in the manual is this specified? that only the space character is used? Maybe other characters like ' or - are accepted and the split could be done there.

Comment: See the syntax. Default is `\n`

Comment: You don't understand what I'm asking. I know the default BREAK character is \n. My question is how does this function decides where to break? It will only search for the nearest space character closest to the width position?